# MD5 $request_body

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm using nginx (and OpenResty) and trying to hash the `$request_body` for caching purposes (with [srcache](https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module)).

When trying to just [`echo`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo) the `$request_body`, it works flawlessly:

```
# actually echoes the request body
location /works {
    # force loading the body
    echo_read_request_body;

    echo $request_body;
}
```

But when trying to calculate the md5, I get the MD5 for an empty string, although I ensure the `$request_body` is loaded via `echo_read_request_body;`.

```
# echoes d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e, which is the MD5 for empty input.
location /doesnt-work-md5 {
    # force loading the body
    echo_read_request_body;

    set_md5 $digest $request_body;
    echo $digest;
}
```

The weirdest phenomenon is that it doesn't even work when just trying to **copy** the variable:

```
# echoes nothing - empty data
location /doesnt-work {
    # force loading the body
    echo_read_request_body;

    set $temp $request_body;
    echo $temp;
}
```

By the way, these latest snippets don't work when using [`$echo_request_body`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo) instead of `$request_body`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [help](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module/issues/40) of the developers of OpenResty, I realized that the `set_XYZ` (i.e. `set`, `set_md5`) are evaluated during nginx's `rewrite` phase, while the `$request_body`/[`$echo_request_body`](https://github.com/openresty/sr) are available only through the `content` phase.

So, when evaluating `set_md5 $digest $request_body;`, `$request_body` variable is empty, which explains the constant MD5 result.

Ultimately I implemented the actual cache key generation in my own API application (see example below), and accessed it with [`access_by_lua`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#access_by_lua) block.

The block runs in the `access` phase, before [`srcache_fetch`](https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module#srcache_fetch) and [`srcache_store`](https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module#srcache_store) are evaluated (they evaluate in `post-access` and `output-filter`, respectively).

Implementing it in my own API allowed greater control over the cache key generation logic, which would be hard to do with nginx alone (since I didn't want to become a full-pledged lua programmer).

For instance, I wanted to be able to *deterministically* cache `POST` requests with Json bodies. Json serialization is not deterministic since keys can be in any order. In my API, I sort the keys so the generated cache key is constant for the same data.

Also, it simplified handling of the `$request_body`, since the lua-issued subrequst just forwards it to the API, regardless of phase or disk buffering status.

The final config looks like

```
location /api {
    # proxy_pass ...
    # Force normal responses (no deflate, etc.) See https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module#srcache_ignore_content_encoding
    proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";

    set $cache_key "";
    access_by_lua_block {
        local res = ngx.location.capture('/generate-key' .. ngx.var.request_uri, {
                method=ngx.HTTP_POST,
                -- forwards the entire request body,
                -- regardless of disk buffering!
                always_forward_body=true,
                args=ngx.var.args
            })

        if res then
            ngx.var.cache_key = res.body
        end
    }

    # ... srcache options ...
}

location /generate-key {
    # proxy_pass ...
}
```

Example key generation API is as follows:

```py
import flask
import json
import hashlib
import urllib


app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/generate', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/generate/<path:path>', methods=['POST'])
def generate_cache_key(path):
    return urllib.quote('{}_{}_{}'.format(path,
        digest(stable_body()),
        digest(stable_json_dumps(flask.request.args))))


def stable_body():
    if flask.request.json:
        return stable_json_dumps(flask.request.json)

    return flask.request.data


def stable_json_dumps(data):
    return json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)


def digest(data):
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I think md5_hash of $request_body should be its own lightweight NGINX plugin. This seems like a prime requirement to enable sensible caching for microservices, especially when they form any kind of pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the nginx phases, i am now able to parse $request_body by using error handlers that run in/after the content phase.

Answer (score -1):

I think what is happening is that you're having a problem with multiple modules running in the locations you have setup. Without the rest of your config I am not sure though.

Can you move your last case to up in the config and test?